# Exclude id from GROUP BY in Jpa Specification

Tags: java, spring, jpa, specifications

I try to use Jpa Specification to build query with Group by. It looks like this:

```
 Specification<AggregatedData> spec = (Specification<AggregatedData>) (root, criteriaQuery, cb) -> {
            Predicate conditions = cb.and(
                    cb.between(root.get("sendDate"), beginDate, endDate),
                    cb.equal(root.get("taskNumber"), taskNum)
            );

            criteriaQuery.multiselect(
                            root.get("file"),
                            root.get("bok"),
                            root.get("taskNumber"),
                            root.get("documentType"),
                            cb.sum(root.get("to8Pages")),
                            cb.sum(root.get("from9To20Pages")),
                    .where(conditions)
                    .groupBy(
                            root.get("file"),
                            root.get("bok"),
                            root.get("taskNumber"),
                            root.get("documentType")
                    ).orderBy(cb.desc(root.get("taskNumber")), cb.desc(root.get("bokNumber")));

            return null;
        };
```

And when I use it, I get the error:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column
> "aggregated0_.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an
> aggregate function

Does it mean I need to add 'id' to my GROUP BY? What if I do not want it? How can I fix my query?

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this
`.orderBy(cb.desc(root.get("taskNumber")), cb.desc(root.get("bokNumber")))`

Comment: Sorry, I had wrong description, I mentioned ORDER BY but my problem is that GROUP BY needs id, but I don't want to include it.